# Spring MVC mapping doesn't work after resources mapping implemented

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my context file I want to add line to be able to access static content. Until I add it, everything works allright, but after I add it, I can't access pages that have some controller and I get this warning: `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/fit/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'`. Before adding `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` to context file, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->




<context:component-scan base-package="cz.cvut.fit.genepi.controllers" />
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-security.xml" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    </beans>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

PS:those pages are secured with Spring security, but I don't think that this could be the problem.

Comment: Please post your Web.xml and One Jsp and Controller also.I wana check how you have mapped incoming requests and how you are using static contents from your JSP page.

Comment: oh..this topic is not actuall in this moment, problem was solved. I'll post the answer with the code. Thanks for reminding :]

Comment: What was the solution? I don't find the answer you talk about :(

Answer (score 1):

Every dispatcher servlet ends with -servlet. 
Try renaming your dispatcher servlet.

On initialization of a DispatcherServlet, the framework will look for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and create the beans defined there.

Comment: that would not be the problem. I've got explicitly defined in `web.xml` the path to dispatcher servlet `<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>` ...And as I've said - everything works well, until I add the line `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`